# Stuck debugging a problem that I think is related to malloc

Tags: c

i'm currently writing a program that makes a sorted linked list in C.  I'm new to C and am running into errors that I think are based around malloc.  I would love if someone can give me some insight on my problems and how to fix them.

These are some of the errors I'm encountering:

==50002==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x563f6970912c bp 0x7ffe5d2b03f0 sp 0x7ffe5d2b03d0 T0)
==50002==The signal is caused by a WRITE memory access.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>
    
    struct node {
        int data;
        struct node* next;
    };
    
    void insert(struct node** n_ref, struct node* newNode) {
    
        struct node* curr;
        if (*n_ref == NULL || (*n_ref)->data >= newNode->data) {
            newNode->next = *n_ref;
            *n_ref = newNode;
        } else {
            curr = *n_ref;
            while (curr->next != NULL && curr->next->data < newNode->data) {
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            newNode->next = curr->next;
            curr->next = newNode;
        }
    }
    
    struct node* makeNode(int num){
        struct node* newNode = NULL;
        newNode->data = num;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    
        return newNode;
    }
    
    void delete(struct node** n, int num) {
    
        struct node* temp = *n, *prev;
    
        if (temp != NULL && temp->data == num) {
            *n = temp->next;
            free(temp);
            return;
        }
    
        while (temp != NULL && temp->data != num) {
            prev = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        if (temp == NULL) {
            return;
        }
    
        prev->next = temp->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    
    void print(struct node* n) {
    
        while (n != NULL) {
            printf("%d ", n->data);
            n = n->next;
        }
    }
    
    int duplicate(struct node* n, int num) {
    
        while (n != NULL) {
            if (n->data == num) {
                return 1;
            }
            n = n->next;
        }
        return 0;
    }
    int main(int argc, char* argv[argc + 1]) {
        if (argc < 2) {
            return EXIT_SUCCESS;
        }
    
        struct node* head = NULL;
    
        FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    
        int x;
        char str[10];
    
        while (fscanf(file, "%s %d\n", str, &x) != EOF) {
            if (strcmp(str, "INSERT")) {
                if (duplicate(head, x) == 0) {
                    struct node* newNode;
                    newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
                    newNode = makeNode(x);
                    insert(&head, newNode);
                }
            } else if (strcmp(str, "DELETE")) {
                delete(&head, x);
            }
            print(head);
        }
        fclose(file);
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
```

Sorry for it being so messy. This is my first post here.

Comment: Aside: `while (fscanf(file, "%s %d\n", str, &x) == 2) {` is a better/stronger test than `while (fscanf(file, "%s %d\n", str, &x) != EOF) {`

Answer (score 0):

The original posted `makeNode()` assigns a local pointer to NULL and dereferences that 2x. Suggest allocating space and check the result, eg:

```
struct node* makeNode(int num) {
    struct node* newNode;

    newNode = malloc(sizeof(*newNode));
    if (newNode) {
        newNode->data = num;
        newNode->next = NULL;
    }

    return newNode;
}
```